# Show hide form elements Jquery/Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of form fields (generated through wtforms) I really only need to show one, and then have an add button:

---

```
<div class=element-work>

            <table id="identifier-0"><tr><th><label for="identifier-0-organization">Organization</label></th><td><input id="identifier-0-organization" name="identifier-0-organization" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-0-position">Position</label></th><td><input id="identifier-0-position" name="identifier-0-position" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-0-start_time">Start</label></th><td><input id="identifier-0-start_time" name="identifier-0-start_time" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-0-end_time">End</label></th><td><input id="identifier-0-end_time" name="identifier-0-end_time" type="text" value=""></td></tr></table>

            <table id="identifier-1"><tr><th><label for="identifier-1-organization">Organization</label></th><td><input id="identifier-1-organization" name="identifier-1-organization" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-1-position">Position</label></th><td><input id="identifier-1-position" name="identifier-1-position" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-1-start_time">Start</label></th><td><input id="identifier-1-start_time" name="identifier-1-start_time" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-1-end_time">End</label></th><td><input id="identifier-1-end_time" name="identifier-1-end_time" type="text" value=""></td></tr></table>

            <table id="identifier-2"><tr><th><label for="identifier-2-organization">Organization</label></th><td><input id="identifier-2-organization" name="identifier-2-organization" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-2-position">Position</label></th><td><input id="identifier-2-position" name="identifier-2-position" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-2-start_time">Start</label></th><td><input id="identifier-2-start_time" name="identifier-2-start_time" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-2-end_time">End</label></th><td><input id="identifier-2-end_time" name="identifier-2-end_time" type="text" value=""></td></tr></table>

            <table id="identifier-3"><tr><th><label for="identifier-3-organization">Organization</label></th><td><input id="identifier-3-organization" name="identifier-3-organization" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-3-position">Position</label></th><td><input id="identifier-3-position" name="identifier-3-position" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-3-start_time">Start</label></th><td><input id="identifier-3-start_time" name="identifier-3-start_time" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-3-end_time">End</label></th><td><input id="identifier-3-end_time" name="identifier-3-end_time" type="text" value=""></td></tr></table>

            <table id="identifier-4"><tr><th><label for="identifier-4-organization">Organization</label></th><td><input id="identifier-4-organization" name="identifier-4-organization" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-4-position">Position</label></th><td><input id="identifier-4-position" name="identifier-4-position" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-4-start_time">Start</label></th><td><input id="identifier-4-start_time" name="identifier-4-start_time" type="text" value=""></td></tr><tr><th><label for="identifier-4-end_time">End</label></th><td><input id="identifier-4-end_time" name="identifier-4-end_time" type="text" value=""></td></tr></table>

</div>
```

---

My options:

1) load all with the page, use js to show/hide fields as needed

2) have js clone/add fields when a button is pressed

Either is fine, but option 1 is the least work at the moment(but I guess more bandwidth consumption in the long run for billions of queries, but I'm not worrying about this now): what is the simplest way with jquery/bootstrap to hide show subsequent parts of the field as necessary? I'm not really a js person, but looking into it it should be simple enough, but I'm posting to see what solutions people have to offer while I work on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.hide()`

```
$('#id').hide();

$('table').hide(); // Hides all the tables

$('#identifier-0').show() // Shows the table wit id="identifier-0"
```

Comment: to hide all the tables in one go -> $("table[id^='identifier-']").hide()